# Which dependency injection is appropriate in the MVC pattern?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa

Let me explain the situation with an example.

Currently, there are teams and members as Models.

```
class Member {
  String name;
  Team team;
}
class Team {
  String teamName;
}
```

There is a MemberRepository that can access the Member database.

```
public interface MemberRepository {
  public Member findByName(String name);
}
```

MemberService that can inquire Member exists.

```
@Service
Memberservice {
    @Autowired
    MemberRepository memberRepository;
    
    public Member searchMember(String name) {
       return memberRepository.findByName(name);
    }
}
```

In this situation, When creating TeamService
If you need to inquire about members , Which one is better to inject, Memberservice  or MemberRepository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the single responsibility principle, you should strive to keep your classes focused on doing a few and related things. With this in mind, *MemberService* should be the only one managing Members and this includes being the only one that touches *MemberRepository*. Having said this you should definitely inject *MemberService*.

As a general rule of thumb, you should avoid multiple Services using the same Repository. If you fail to do so you might end up with spaghetti code. This means that Services should "communicate" between them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
However, when injecting dependencies between Service
What do you think about dependencies that can cause circular references?

Comment: Circular references usually mean that your class design is not the right one. This might not be true for every single situation, but. it is usually a hint that you should change it. If you provide an example I can try to suggest some changes.